# Disable Copy/Paste to Excel from other sources

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I want to disable the copy/paste function so people cannot paste anything over a workbook I created.

Using the below code, I succeeded in preventing people from copying from another workbook to this one or vice versa.

However, they can still copy from other non-Excel sources, such as Outlook or an internet browser. If it doesn't come from excel, it can be pasted into this workbook. How do I prevent this so that no pasting can occur in the workbook whatsoever?

Code in Module:

```
Sub ToggleCutCopyAndPaste(Allow As Boolean)
     'Activate/deactivate cut, copy, paste and pastespecial menu items
    Call EnableMenuItem(21, Allow) ' cut
    Call EnableMenuItem(19, Allow) ' copy
    Call EnableMenuItem(22, Allow) ' paste
    Call EnableMenuItem(755, Allow) ' pastespecial

         'Activate/deactivate drag and drop ability
        Application.CellDragAndDrop = Allow

         'Activate/deactivate cut, copy, paste and pastespecial shortcut keys
        With Application
            Select Case Allow
            Case Is = False
                .OnKey "^c", ""
                .OnKey "^v", ""
                .OnKey "^x", ""
                .OnKey "^{DEL}", ""
                .OnKey "^{INSERT}", ""
            Case Is = True
                .OnKey "^c"
                .OnKey "^v"
                .OnKey "^x"
                .OnKey "^{DEL}"
                .OnKey "^{INSERT}"
            End Select
        End With
    End Sub

    Sub EnableMenuItem(ctlId As Integer, Enabled As Boolean)
         'Activate/Deactivate specific menu item
        Dim cBar As CommandBar
        Dim cBarCtrl As CommandBarControl
        For Each cBar In Application.CommandBars
            If cBar.Name <> "Clipboard" Then
                Set cBarCtrl = cBar.FindControl(ID:=ctlId, recursive:=True)
                If Not cBarCtrl Is Nothing Then cBarCtrl.Enabled = Enabled
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

Code in ThisWorkbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Call ToggleCutCopyAndPaste(False)
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
    Call ToggleCutCopyAndPaste(False)
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Call ToggleCutCopyAndPaste(True)
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
    Call ToggleCutCopyAndPaste(True)
End Sub
```

Comment: Perhaps empty the buffer every time a cell is selected - or a **Window** is activated? That should cover most eventualities.

Comment: What about blocking cells? You already managed how to prevent people from copying from another workbook to this one or vice versa. Try now blocking cells so nobody can change any value in that workbook.

Comment: Protecting the sheet, but allowing data validation so they can enter either numbers in a range or select from options.

Comment: I added the following to the code:
Private Sub Workbook_WindowActivate()
    Call ToggleCutCopyAndPaste(False)
End Sub
However, the issue is unresolved.
The sheet is protected. No cells can be changed with the exception of unlocked cells where I want users to be able to add data.

This specific problem arose when one user joined who copies everything from their emails or online to the workbook. I then learned the workbook wasn't impervious. When the user does this, the formatting changes, fields get moved and unlocked cells become locked. I cannot explain why the latter happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found another method that disables people being able to paste into the workbook from Outlook, an internet browser, etc. No module needed. Just drop the below code in ThisWorkbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
Application.CutCopyMode = True
Application.OnKey "^c"
Application.OnKey "^v"
Application.OnKey "^{INSERT}",
Application.OnKey "^{DELETE}",
Application.CommandBars("Cell").Enabled = True
Application.CellDragAndDrop = True
Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",True)"
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.OnKey "^c", ""
Application.OnKey "^v", ""
Application.OnKey "^{INSERT}", ""
Application.OnKey "^{DELETE}", ""
Application.CommandBars("Cell").Enabled = False
Application.CellDragAndDrop = False
'use if statement here if you want to situationally keep ribbon
Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",False)"
'Else
'Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",True)"
'End If
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.OnKey "^c", ""
Application.OnKey "^v", ""
Application.OnKey "^{INSERT}", ""
Application.OnKey "^{DELETE}", ""
Application.CommandBars("Cell").Enabled = False
Application.CellDragAndDrop = False
'use if statement here if you want to situationally keep ribbon
Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",False)"
'Else
'Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",True)"
'End If
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
Application.CellDragAndDrop = True
Application.OnKey "^c"
Application.OnKey "^v"
Application.OnKey "^{INSERT}"
Application.OnKey "^{DELETE}"
Application.CommandBars("Cell").Enabled = True
Application.CutCopyMode = True
Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",True)"
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_WindowActivate(ByVal Wn As Window)
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.OnKey "^c", ""
Application.OnKey "^v", ""
Application.OnKey "^{INSERT}", ""
Application.OnKey "^{DELETE}", ""
Application.CommandBars("Cell").Enabled = False
Application.CellDragAndDrop = False
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_WindowDeactivate(ByVal Wn As Window)
Application.CellDragAndDrop = True
Application.OnKey "^c"
Application.OnKey "^v"
Application.OnKey "^{INSERT}"
Application.OnKey "^{DELETE}"
Application.CommandBars("Cell").Enabled = True
Application.CutCopyMode = True
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
Application.OnKey "^c", ""
Application.OnKey "^v", ""
Application.OnKey "^{INSERT}", ""
Application.OnKey "^{DELETE}", ""
Application.CommandBars("Cell").Enabled = False
Application.CellDragAndDrop = False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Note that I've disabled the ribbon as well, as it's still possible to paste using the Home tab. Frustrating that there doesn't seem to be a way to disable copy/paste completely and not just from Excel to Excel.

If you want, you can put this code in a module and run it manually when you need to access copy/paste tools:

```
Sub Enable_CopyPaste()

'Run this sub when you need to access copy/paste tools

Application.CutCopyMode = True
Application.OnKey "^c"
Application.OnKey "^v"
Application.OnKey "^{INSERT}"
Application.OnKey "^{DELETE}"
Application.CommandBars("Cell").Enabled = True
Application.CellDragAndDrop = True
Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",True)"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to CLR for pointing out window activation. I added this to ThisWorkbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
    Call ToggleCutCopyAndPaste(True)
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_WindowActivate(ByVal Wn As Window)
    Call ToggleCutCopyAndPaste(False)
End Sub
```

Whilst it didn't initially fix the problem, it did in conjunction with this code added to the Module:

```
Dim oData   As New DataObject 'object to use the clipboard

    oData.SetText Text:=Empty 'Clear
    oData.PutInClipboard 'take in the clipboard to empty it
```

Now users can't displace and reformat the contents of the workbook via copy/pasting from Outlook, internet browsers, etc.

Comment: I'm revisiting this as there are still methods to bypass the disabled copy/paste which is an issue.